# Set Child Component TextField's Value to Parent Components Dropdown Selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parent-child, tsx

In the following two codes, There is a child and a parent component. The child component has a TextField, and the parent component has Dropdown, is there a way I can set the TextField's value to whatever I change the Parent Dropdown to? For example, if I selected "Medium", I want to change the child component TextField's value to "Medium". Is this possible?

Here is the Child Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/';
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return( 
          <TextField
              label="Description" required
              key="descriptionKey"
              styles={props.styles}
              value={props.value} 
              multiline={props.multiline}
              onChange={props.onChange}
              defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
              placeholder={props.placeholder}
            />
    );
}
export default ChildComponent;
```

Here is the Parent Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import ChildComponent from './ListItem';
import { Dropdown, IDropdownOption } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            operationType: event.target.value,
        })
    };
render(){
    const riskAssess: IDropdownOption[] = [
        { key: 'high', text: 'High' },
        { key: 'medium', text: 'Medium' },
        { key: 'low', text: 'Low' },
      ]
    return(
    <div>
        <Dropdown
          label="Risk Assessment" required
          ariaLabel="Risk"
          styles={{ dropdown: { width: 125 } }}
          options={riskAssess}
          onChange={this._onChange}
        />
        <ChildComponent value="This is what I want to change to Dropdown value" />
    </div>
      );
   }
   private _onChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, item: IDropdownOption): void => {
    this.setState({operationType: item.text})
    console.log(event);
  };
}
export default ParentComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Replace `"This is what I want to change to Dropdown value"` with `{this.state.operationType}`. The curly braces tell JSX that you want a variable to populate that value.

With TypeScript, your components need to define their property and state structures, by adding generic arguments to React.Component:

```
interface ParentProps = {};

interface ParentState = {
  operationType: string;
};

class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentProps, ParentState> {
```

For ChildComponent, you'd want to extend React.FC (short for FunctionalComponent) in a similar way. Since it doesn't define any state, it can forego the second generic argument:

```
interface ChildProps {
  styles?: React.CSSProperties;
  value?: string;
  multiline?: boolean;
  onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
  defaultValue?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
};

const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildProps> = (props) => {
```

Now TypeScript knows what to expect.

TypeScript's precise interface definitions ensure that each component gets only what it allows. It replaces React's PropTypes warnings with enforced compilation errors. It's more complex, having to define all this, but it makes for less error-prone development.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for the response! I am getting the following error: "Property 'operationType' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'. ts(2239)"

Comment: is it very different than JavaScript? or is something like brackets around it?

Comment: It's like JavaScript with armor. You have to spend some time defining exactly how your functions and classrs play with each other. I really like it, but it can be mind-bending.

Comment: thank you very much! I am not getting any errors, however, my Task Pane seems to be freezing and it is just giving me a white screen. Is there anything that I am typing wrong? I added my code above

Comment: I'd open up the dev tools in your browser and see if any errors are there, then it's off on a Debugging Adventure!

Comment: i am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'operationType' of null"

Comment: (I don't see anything wrong with the code, but I also don't know this particular library.)

Comment: Ohhh! Try creating an initial state in a constructor: `constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { operationType: ''}; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211003/discussion-between-ethan-and-michael-landis).